# Add anchor option in Rails link_to using array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, anchor, erb, link-to

I'm using an array to generate the path for my rails link_to tags and can't seem to figure out how to add an anchor option. Here are my link_to tags:

```
<%= link_to pluralize(post.comments.count, 'comment'), [post.postable, post] %>

<%= link_to "Leave a comment", [post.postable, post] %>
```

Since I'm using a polymorphic association for the posts (and they are nested routes), I can't simply use the paths generated by the resources helpers in the routes.rb file.

Previously, I was able to use the anchor option on the paths automagically generated as I was not using the polymorphic association with this model. This is what that looked like:

```
<%= link_to pluralize(post.comments.count, 'comment'), project_post_path(@project, post, {anchor: 'comments'}) %>

<%= link_to "Leave a comment", project_post_path(@project, post, {anchor: 'new-comment'}) %>
```

Any tips on how to get an anchor tag back into the link_to tags when using an array to generate the url? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call [`polymorphic_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html#method-i-polymorphic_path):

```
<%= link_to pluralize(post.comments.count, 'comment'), polymorphic_path([post.postable, post], anchor: 'comments') %>

<%= link_to "Leave a comment", polymorphic_path([post.postable, post], anchor: 'new-comment') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "Leave a comment", [post.postable, post], :anchor=> 'new-comment' %>
```

Comment: that doesn't work. I tried that previously, it simply doesn't add anything.